# GAM correcting for spatial autocorrelation with repeated measurements with a nested block design

Tags: r, gam, mgcv, autocorrelation

I want to model the species counts across a range of environmental conditions (continuous and categorical variables) from a field experiment. Across the area's nested treatment blocks (4 species/block) were used with repeated measurements. I have been trying to use the r mgcv package with the gam() function. I am using gam instead of glm because of non-linearity in the data.

I identified that I have spatial autocorrelations using DHARMa, testSpatialAutocorrelation(). I tried to correct for this by adding a smoother for the coordinates via s(x,y) or by adding Block id as a random factor s(Block, bs ='re'), however this is not sufficient to solve it. Below the model structure that I am currently using without these elements, how could I correctly specify this nested design as well as correcting for the spatial auto correlation?

model <- gam(SpeciesCount ~ Species + MonitoringMoment + StudyArea + V1 + s(V2, by = Species) + s(V3) + s(SV4), data = Data, method = 'REML', family = nb())

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: What is MonitoringMovement and why is it included as a linear term as well as within a pure tensor interaction? This doesn’t make sense to me.

Comment: Monitoring moment indicates the respective field campaign. The abundance of the species was counted at 4 different moments across a year, for the moment I included it as a categorical variable. I apologize, I made a mistake writing down the model, I mixed two. The tensors should not have been in there, I have edited the post.